# Creating an analog clock on C#

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2008

I intend in creating a few analog clocks on Visual Studio 2008 (C#) for a school project, but I'm am still a bit unsure on how show I do it..

Should I import an image of a pointer and then add the codes to it to make it spin?

Or should I use some sort of code to actually draw the pointers and move them?

**EDIT:**

Been looking around the internet but I am not sure on how should I begin... never used any properties on how to actually draw something on C#, can someone tell me how should I proceed to make an analog clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier to draw the hands than to rotate images of the hands, especially since you will need one image for each hand and the images will conflict with each other.

Comment: He could use transparent png:s for the hands though.

Comment: @aL3891: Yeah, but it's a school project.  In the absence of any requirement to use images (or extra credit earned), I think simply drawing some lines for the hands would suffice.

Comment: it will, also because it is somewhat a freelance project, the analog clock is actually an option I made to make the program look better than just text

Answer (score 0):

However you choose to do the hands (images or xaml shapes) you'd then animate them with the [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) Msdn has a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743037.aspx) too

You could also use databinding and a timer to change the rotation every second